# I need to replace code written with union all as it is getting hung during execute

Tags: sql, oracle, union-all

I have a table that has primary key coa_key and it has 7 fields labeled extract_code1, extract_code2...

The code written now select the key with code1  and inserts it into table2 if it does not exist in table 2 already.

```
INSERT INTO ef_extract_codes_t
  SELECT coa_key, extract_code1
  FROM ef_load_it l
  WHERE extract_code1 IS NOT NULL AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT e.coa_key||e.extract_code
                    FROM   ef_extract_codes_t e
                    WHERE  e.coa_key||e.extract_code = l.coa_key||extract_code1)
```

The union all is the same as above except code2 and then repeats till all 7 codes are checked.

Can someone help me with a better way to write this so as not to hang?

Comment: So you want to load all rows from table ef_load_it into table ef_extract_codes_t, but not the rows where the primary key and any pair of extract_code columns match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a guess since you haven't posted a profile of the "hung" execution, but it sounds like you could use the `MERGE` command.

But you may not have to go to the extreme of a rewrite if your statement is functionally correct and your indexes are adequate. Since most people would probably *not* create indexes with the expression you give, `e.coa_key||e.extract_code`, I'd recommend replacing

```
e.coa_key||e.extract_code = l.coa_key||extract_code1
```

with this:

```
e.coa_key = l.coa_key and e.extract_code = l.extract_code1
```

I believe this will work if `coa_key` and `extract_code` cannot be null. If they can be null then you need to decide how to handle that situation.

Comment: This process right now has 10 million records to insert. The cursor causes 7 million iterations.  Now maybe hung is not the right term.  With that many iterations we are looking at 1944 hours approximately.

Comment: @user3465081 You are wise to suspect an inefficient execution plan. If you show the statement's execution plan including execution statistics (logical reads, blocks physically read, elapsed time estimates) for each rowsource operation, then you might get different (possibly better) advice.

Comment: Here is the next section.  It won't let me add all the code.
      UNION ALL
      SELECT coa_key, extract_code2
   FROM ef_load_it l
   WHERE extract_code2 is not null and
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT e.coa_key||e.extract_code
                        FROM   ef_extract_codes_t e
                        WHERE  e.coa_key||e.extract_code = l.coa_key||extract_code2)

Comment: Hash Value Cursors Total Time Parses Executions Fetches Avg Dep
3594028925 1 374.160652 0 6 0 1